# How to send Flutter Quill json with an image in post api

Tags: flutter, image, post, quill

I'm trying to send json of flutter quill json with an image in post api request. My json is look like this which contains a text and image

```
[{"insert":"\n\n\nFlutter quill\n\n"},{"insert":{"image":"/data/user/0/com.appsnado.thechampionshiproutine/cache/image_picker2859034745323535916.webp"}},{"insert":"\n"}]
```

I'm getting the json from below code

```
var json;
QuillController quillController = QuillController.basic();
setState(() {
  json = jsonEncode(quillController.document.toDelta().toJson());
});
```

so here you can see image path is of my device and normally when we send an image in post api we use `path` library, but how we can use it here?

I hope my question is clear, please help how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

we can pass this json to api endpoint.

```
jsonData = jsonEncode(quillController.document.toDelta().toJson());
```

```
var headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  };
  var data = json.encode({
    "content":jsonData
  });
  var dio = Dio();
  var response = await dio.request(
    'api-end-point',
    options: Options(
      method: 'POST',
      headers: headers,
    ),
    data: data,
  );
```